# Paypal openSSL error

Tags: paypal, openssl

I am trying to set up Paypal on my site, the problem is that I am currently OVH has 0.9.8o version of OpenSSL, or it appears that Paypal is required from version 1.0.2 to run.

The error comes from line 2:

```
if($this->getParameter('paypal_sandbox') == true)
    $fp = fsockopen('tls://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
else
    $fp = fsockopen('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
```

This is error return :

```
"Warning: fsockopen(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure"
```

Besides, I also want to know if for line 4 must use it well "ssl://" or does it put "tls://" as for the sandbox environment ?

Thank you !

Comment: What, exactly, is your question? Are you having problems in the sandbox? If so, see [Socket connection error connecting to sandbox at www.sandbox.paypal.com](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35247019)

Comment: Hello,

Thank you for your answer, my question is is there a way to solve this problem without updating openSSL (0.9.8o) because my OVH does not wish to upgrade, so I find myself blocked.

The problem is he good at this?

My second question is should it well use "ssl: //" instead of "tls: //" to prod api paypal?

Comment: I also want to up the topic